# PhoneAuthProvider not getting resolved?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created and configured firebase project and enabled the phone number verification and added the dependency

gradle: project level

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

gradle module level

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am not able to resolve PhoneAuthProvider

```
private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
// [START start_phone_auth]
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
        60,                 // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
        this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
        mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks}
```

Followed all steps from [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) documents

Comment: are you using emulator for testing because `phone number sign-in requires a physical device and won't work on an emulator`

Comment: first of all this is not getting resolve so how one can run the application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phone authentication was added in [version 11.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#sdk_releases_24). You'll need to change your build.gradle to require at least that version:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
```

Comment: Oh yes exactly. Thanks Frank.

Comment: Thanks, really surprised the google docs didn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just import class for the required method. For example, if you want to use `getInstance()` method, then you have to import class `PhoneAuthProvider` at top.
Make sure that you have connected your project with firebase.

Like:

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
```